# When scaffolding identity in Blazor Server 6 and overriding IdentityUser, Login and register do not work anymore

Tags: blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

Steps to reproduce:

- Create new Blazor 6 Server project, with individual account
- Updated all Nuget packages to the latest version
- Override the default identityuser class (applicationuser) and add some custom properties.
  Setup DBContent as following:

> ```
> public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
> {
>     public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
>         : base(options)
>     {
>     }
> }
> ```

- Change IdentityUser to ApplicationUser here
- Scaffolded identity, so all Razor account views are created.
- Add and apply an EF migration, the extra properties are added to the database.
- Change startup.cs as following:

> ```
> var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
> builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
>     options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
> builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
>     .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
> ```

- App runs fine but when I try the register a user, it fails on the following:

[image]

I created this test project from scratch, no upgrades. So it created the user (verified in database), but when retrieving it from the database fails.

Logging in with this user also fails with a similar error
[image]

Did someone get this working ? Or have some guidance on what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a workaround. I scaffolded identity with the default IdentityUser, then went through all the Identity pages and changed the user class.

That worked.

These properties were nullable (strings) but the new columns were added to the database